# How to find user activities on a particular database in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

Which query shows the user activities on a partiular database in SQL Server 2000? I need to know which all users are loged in one of the databases and also need to see the queries fired by these users

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Show_my_process] (@SPID INT) 
returns VARCHAR(8000) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @sql_handle   BINARY(20), 
              @handle_found BIT 
      DECLARE @stmt_start INT, 
              @stmt_end   INT 
      DECLARE @line     NVARCHAR(4000), 
              @wait_str VARCHAR(8) 
      DECLARE @sql_process AS VARCHAR(8000) 

      SELECT @sql_handle = sql_handle, 
             @stmt_start = stmt_start / 2, 
             @stmt_end = CASE 
                           WHEN stmt_end = -1 THEN -1 
                           ELSE stmt_end / 2 
                         END 
      FROM   master.dbo.sysprocesses 
      WHERE  spid = @spid 
             AND ecid = 0 

      SELECT @sql_process = Substring(text, COALESCE(NULLIF(@stmt_start, 0), 1),
                             CASE 
                                   @stmt_end 
                            WHEN -1 
                                   THEN 
                                   Datalength(text) 
                                   ELSE ( 
                                                  @stmt_end - @stmt_start ) 
                            END) 
      FROM   ::fn_get_sql(@sql_handle) 

      RETURN @sql_process 
  END  

SELECT dbo.SHOW_MY_PROCESS(SPID) 
FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES 
WHERE SPID > 50
```

If I run this I get the queries but the problem is I can not see the queries run by other users

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [sp_who](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) it is what you look for.

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_who 'active';
GO
```

Comment: @user1254579 It returns `cmd` column

Comment: how to display the queries run by users as one of the columns